# I end up as a Criminal

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I am (kind of) a number
>
> That ends with a number

> I get enraged
>
> When you add a starting number

> I become a criminal
>
> When you add a different starting number

What four letter word am I?

Comment: What is meant by starting number, or we have to figure it out ourselves?

Comment: rot 13 ahzore ng gur fgneg bs gur jbeq

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I am a (kind of) number that ends with a number

> rate - used to specify a number e.g. interest rate, and it ends with the number e

I get enraged when you add a starting number

> irate - by adding the number i

I become a criminal when you add a different number

> pirate - by adding the number pi

Comment: rot13(Nyfb "ngr" pbhyq or frra nf cubargvpnyyl fvzvyvne gb "rvtug", juvpu bs pbhefr vf nyfb n ahzore.)

Comment: For anyone who is confused (like I was), the letter e is also the irrational constant 2.718281828... and i refers to the imaginary unit which is equal to the square root of -1